# Get attribute value from JSON

Tags: php, json

```
object(stdClass)#43 (3) { ["@promo"]=> string(4) "true" ["@rate"]=> string(6) "308.69" ["@baseRate"]=> string(6) "342.99" }
```

The above is the partial output from a JSON file. The original file is actually an XML file.

```
<NightlyRate promo="true" rate="227.09" baseRate="283.86"/>
```

I used jsondecode to convert the XML to json. However, I don't know how to get the values for each of the attribute.

Ex, i want to get 227.09 and 283.86 using JSON.

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: please use either JSON or XML. thanks

Comment: None of these are programming languages. Which **programming language** would you like to use for this task?

Comment: Oops, I am using PHP. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Why not use something like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) to work with the XML directly, rather than go through the common (yet, completely misguided) xml-to-json-to-array conversions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do find the entire process a bit odd, but you can access invalid variable name properties of `stdClass` using this syntax:

```
$stdClassVar->{"@rate"};
```

Comment: yeah, i find it weird too...but the API returns me this. I have no control over the format. Thanks so much for helping.